# Close IE process from java program

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, process

I wrote a program to open IE using

```
Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec();
```

now I want to close this instance of IE on a button click from my Swing GUI.
I tried `process.destroy()` but it's not working.
I also read about process.waitfor() but that's only called after IE is closed, i.e., I manually close IE.

Also if I use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe");
```

it kills all the instances of IE running.
I only want to close the IE associated with my process above.

Please suggest what should I do ?

Comment: Which version of windows are you using? And what happens on `process.destroy()`?

Answer (score 1):

For Internet Explorer9, this is not going to be simple.  The way IE9 handles multiple windows and its processes limits the options on closing selective windows by killing the process.

Even when you find the right process, killing it might result in killing all other IE windows.

IE uses `SysFader` to manage other windows and tabs, when trying to kill the right one it will attempt to recover it.

You can search and look into external libraries like [SIGAR](http://www.hyperic.com/support/docs/sigar/org/hyperic/sigar/Sigar.html) which allows you to query for the process.

---

For other processes there might be a way to tag the process when starting it then saving the `PID` for the when we need to close it.

*Example just to demonstrate the idea, do not use this*

```
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmssSSS");
String tag = "test"+formatter.format(date);

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe www.google.com/search?q=" + tag );
p.waitFor();
```

This will tag the process, because in the verbose `TASKLIST` there is a 'Window Title' that will display this tag.

Then, by parsing the list you can determine the `PID`

```
Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("TASKLIST /V /FI \"IMAGENAME eq iexplore.exe\"");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()));
String line, pid = "";
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
   if(line.contains(tag)){
      String[] taskTokens = line.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim().split(" ");
      pid = taskTokens[1];
      System.out.println("PID:"+pid);
   }
}
input.close();
```

Then if you want to close the specified PID you can call

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("TASKKILL /PID " + pid);
```

When you test this with IE9 you will notice the `SysFader` which will give you the same PID as it creates new process, but the last one called will have the same `PID` as the one before, which gets a new `PID`.

I cannot test with any other version..  Feel free to customize the idea for your needs

Comment: thanks Hitham...I also came to the same work around u suggested....but i'm looking for something simple and straight....by the way thanks

Comment: do you mean there is some straight way for IE 8.0.xxx and earlier ?

Comment: probably, because the tabs concept was not implemented then